# Building pagination in MVC: Is there anyway to get something like an Html.HyperLinkFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paging

What I mean by that is a  type element that will have a label based on a value in my viewModel and also be able to submit that value back up to the viewModel so it can grab new results based on Current Page and Page Size. This is for creating a gridview in MVC that supports pagination.

None of the examples I've seen of MVC so far have had anything resembling a gridview. It's important that I create my own paging and not use any built in paging mechanisms or third party controls or html helpers or the like

Comment: So, you want to build everything from scratch? That's OK. In this case what is your question? Do you have some particular problems you have encountered when you tried to implement it and you would like to ask about? Some code snippet to show us? What exactly do you expect?

Comment: I don't know how to get MVC to associate a HyperLink with a value in my viewModel. What I'm looking to do is have something like CurrentPage as a variable in my viewmodel and have the hyperlinks update that page number. Likewise the label on that hyperlink or linkbutton would be set by a for loop depending on the current page (meaning I don't want page 1 button to display if the user is on page 2, etc.) Data layer would then get correct values with LINQ Take And Skip.

Comment: Maybe [MVCContrib Pagination source code](http://code.google.com/p/mvccontrib/source/browse/trunk/src/MVCContrib/Pagination/?r=359) could give you an inspiration.

Comment: Bit of googling yields this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/implement-efficient-data-paging Seems the easiest way to do this in MVC is to either a) use AJAX b) use the querystring to keep track of paging/sorting variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with ActionLink. To build Urls you can either  use Url.Action or Html.BuildUrlFromExpression(c => c.conTrollerAction)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC), you will get some nice helpers that do exactly what you are looking for.

Something along the lines of:

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action(MVC.MyController.MyAction(Model.ActionMethodParam1, Model.ActionMethodParam2)) %>">
```

You can also use the Html.ActionLink helper:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Link Name", MVC.MyController.MyAction(Model.ActionMethodParam1, Model.ActionMethodParam2)) %>
```

T4MVC is a great little library that I use in *every* MVC app.